# How can I prevent pickerInput options in a shinydashboard sidebar menu from cutting off when the mouse moves outside the sidebar?

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinywidgets

I've added a shinywidgets::pickerInput into my R shinydashboard sidebarMenu.

When the pickerInput is open, and the cursor is hovered over it, I can see all 5 options in the pickerInput no problem. However when the cursor is moved to anywhere outside of the sidebarMenu - either below or into the main body, the options are cut off, and I can only see the first 2 options.

I understand they are cut off *because* they spill outside the sidebarMenu area - however there is no need for the display to cut off in this circumstance.

Can I change this behaviour? Ideally, no options would be cut off, wherever the cursor is moved.

Or I would be happy for the pickerInput to 'auto close' if the cursor is moved outside of the pickerInput (but I don't know how to do that either!)

**Update** - I have tried adding `pickerOptions(size = 5)` to my code, but despite the documentation which says "the menu will show the given number of items, even if the dropdown is cut off" it does **not** prevent the options from cutting off when the mouse is moved.

**Update** - my reproducible example!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Helper function 
convertMenuItem <- function(mi,tabName) {
  mi$children[[1]]$attribs['data-toggle']="tab"
  mi$children[[1]]$attribs['data-value'] = tabName
  if(length(mi$attribs$class)>0 && mi$attribs$class=="treeview"){
    mi$attribs$class=NULL
  }
  mi
}


# Define UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Demo"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      convertMenuItem(
        menuItem(text = "Option1", 
                 tabName = "opt1",
                 shinyWidgets::pickerInput(inputId = "picker",
                                           label = "Select:",
                                           choices = c("Pick 1", "Pick 2", "Pick 3", "Pick 4", "Pick 5", "Pick 6"),
                                           selected = c(""),
                                           multiple = TRUE,
                                           options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, 
                                                          `dropdownAlignRight` = TRUE,
                                                          `dropupAuto` = TRUE))),
        tabName = "opt1-outer"),
      menuItem("Option2", tabName = "opt2"),
      menuItem("Option3", tabName = "opt3")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
  )
)
# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: illustration of the problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The open dropdown-menu has `display: block;` by default. You can change this to `display: contents;` by adding

```
.open > .dropdown-menu {
    display: contents;
}
```

and then all options remain visible when you hover away.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Helper function 
convertMenuItem <- function(mi,tabName) {
    mi$children[[1]]$attribs['data-toggle']="tab"
    mi$children[[1]]$attribs['data-value'] = tabName
    if(length(mi$attribs$class)>0 && mi$attribs$class=="treeview"){
        mi$attribs$class=NULL
    }
    mi
}


# Define UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Demo"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            convertMenuItem(
                menuItem(text = "Option1", 
                         tabName = "opt1",
                         shinyWidgets::pickerInput(inputId = "picker",
                                                   label = "Select:",
                                                   choices = c("Pick 1", "Pick 2", "Pick 3", "Pick 4", "Pick 5", "Pick 6"),
                                                   selected = c(""),
                                                   multiple = TRUE,
                                                   options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, 
                                                                  `dropdownAlignRight` = TRUE,
                                                                  `dropupAuto` = TRUE))),
                tabName = "opt1-outer"),
            menuItem("Option2", tabName = "opt2"),
            menuItem("Option3", tabName = "opt3")
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                                  .open > .dropdown-menu {
                                      display: contents;
                                  }
                                 ")))
    )
)
# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
    
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the number of options displayed like:

```
pickerInput(
  ## ...
  options = pickerOptions(size = 5)
)
```

From `?pickerOptions`:

> When set to 'auto', the menu always opens up to show as many items as the window will allow without being cut off. *When set to an integer*, the menu will show the given number of items, *even if the dropdown is cut off*. When set to false, the menu will always show all items. Type: 'auto' | integer | false; Default: 'auto'.

(Emphasis by me)

Comment: Thanks for answering! But I'm afraid the options still cut off in the exact same way if you include `size = 5` as you suggest.